# Mocking parameter array on method setup is not binding

Tags: moq

I am trying to setup the following method call:

```
public Entity GetById(int id, params Expression<Func<Entity, object>>[] includes)
{
}
```

Here is my setup:

```
var mock = new Mock<Caller>();
mock.Setup(caller => caller.GetById(It.Is<int>(id => id == request.Id),
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity, object>>[]>()))
.Returns(fakeEntity);
```

This compiles just fine. However, at runtime, I get the following error:

`Moq.MockException: Caller.GetById(1, ex1 => ex1, ex2 => ex2, ex3 => ex3) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.`

So I tried switching to loose behavior instead but, as expected, it returned a `Mock<Entity>` rather than `fakeEntity`. Why isn't the mock signature correctly binding to the method signature?

Comment: Why does `GetById` in the error have 4 arguments, but your mock setup only has 2?

Comment: It's a parameter array created with the params keyword.